# nav-bar: align inline text, left and right

Tags: html, css, alignment, navbar

Basically, I want "Name" to go to the left of the nav-bar, while "About" "Contact" and "Account" remain on the right of the nav-bar.

https://jsfiddle.net/etw2q6sL/1/

```
.name {
  font-family: "ChunkFive"; /* works */
  font-size: 22px;          /* works */
  color: #32B432;           /* doesn't */
  text-align: left;         /* doesn't */
}
```

I used **li class="name"**, within a **ul**, within a **div id**, within a **nav class**.

I don't know which parent or child styles to change. (I wanted to change the color of "Name" to green too but it wasn't working either).

Comment: position:absolute;
  top:-560px;
  left:30px;  put that in your name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an update to your Fiddle that should do what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/etw2q6sL/4/

The colour rule not working is because your other rule `#mainNav a` specifies a colour for all the links in the nav, and this is more specific than your `.name` rule, so the browser chooses the colour from the former. To make this work as you want, I would make the `.name` rule more specific by adding extra conditions to its selector - e.g. change it to `#mainNav .name a`. To learn more about CSS specificity (the order in which rules are applied) check this out: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

On the alignment issue, you're confusing text alignment with placement of your list items. `text-align: left` will simply take align any inline content (such as text, spans, etc.) and align it to the left in the current list item - it won't align the list item to the left in the nav.

Instead what you want for this is a `float`. What I've done is separate out your list into two separate uls, one which has a `float: left` applied and the other a `float: right`. These floats pull the two lists to the left and right side of the nav. This article may help you learn about using floats with a navbar like you're making: http://www.cssnewbie.com/super-simple-horizontal-navigation-bar/

Comment: thanks for the articles as well! always helpful for a beginner

Comment: No problem, hope they help you out - it's pretty simple stuff when you get the hang of it but seems like a minefield at first if you don't fully understand certain CSS rules. They're not without their foibles and exceptions.